# how to combine nested common object value using javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Input:**

```
let array = [
  {
    "raw_name": "At high school",
    "id": "1",
    "name": "At high school",
    "type": "education_statuses",
    "path": [
      "Demographics",
      "Education",
      "Education level"
    ]
  },
  {
    "raw_name": "At university",
    "id": "2",
    "name": "At university",
    "type": "education_statuses",
    "path": [
      "Demographics",
      "Education",
      "Education level"
    ]
  },
  {
    "raw_name": "At university (postgraduate)",
    "id": "7",
    "name": "At university (postgraduate)",
    "type": "education_statuses",
    "path": [
      "Interest",
      "Sports"
    ]
  },
  {
    "raw_name": "Doctorate degree",
    "id": "11",
    "name": "Doctorate degree",
    "type": "education_statuses",
    "path": [
      "Interest",
      "Sports"
    ]
  },
  {
    "raw_name": "Foundation degree",
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Foundation degree",
    "type": "education_statuses",
    "path": [
      "Demographics",
      "Education"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "label": "Demographics",
    "value": [
      {
        "label": "Education",
        "value": [
          {
            "label": "Education level",
            "value": [
              {
                "raw_name": "At high school",
                "id": "1",
                "name": "At high school",
                "type": "education_statuses",
                "path": [
                  "Demographics",
                  "Education",
                  "Education level"
                ]
              },
              {
                "raw_name": "At university",
                "id": "2",
                "name": "At university",
                "type": "education_statuses",
                "path": [
                  "Demographics",
                  "Education",
                  "Education level"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "raw_name": "Foundation degree",
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Foundation degree",
            "type": "education_statuses",
            "path": [
              "Demographics",
              "Education"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Interest",
    "value": [
      {
        "label": "Sports",
        "value": [
          {
            "raw_name": "Cricket",
            "id": "11",
            "name": "Cricket",
            "type": "Cricket_statuses",
            "path": [
              "Interest",
              "Sports"
            ]
          },
          {
            "raw_name": "Football",
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Football",
            "type": "Football_statuses",
            "path": [
              "Interest",
              "Sports"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Explanion:**

If you check input object

```
{
    "raw_name": "At high school",
    "id": "1",
    "name": "At high school",
    "type": "education_statuses",
    "path": [
      "Demographics",
      "Education",
      "Education level"
    ]
 }
```

it has key called `path` which has multiple levels. so in output object will be

```
{
    "label": "Demographics",
    "value": [
      {
        "label": "Education",
        "value": [
          {
            "label": "Education level",
            "value": [
                {
                    "raw_name": "At high school",
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "At high school",
                    "type": "education_statuses",
                    "path": [
                      "Demographics",
                      "Education",
                      "Education level"
                    ]
                 }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is my code which i tried but unable to achive correct object structure

```
 function init() {
   let dataArr = array;
   let arr = [];
   let arrNew = [];
   dataArr.forEach((value, key) => {
      let d = value.path;
      let obj={};
      if(d.length == 1) {
         obj['label'] = d[0];
         obj['value'] = [value];
      } else if(d.length == 2) {

         obj['label'] = d[0];
         obj['value'] = [
            {
               'label': d[1],
               'value': [value]
            }
         ];

      } else if(d.length == 3) {

         obj['label'] = d[0];
         obj['value'] = [{
            'label': d[1],
            'value': [
               {
                  label: d[2],
                  value: [value]
               }
            ]
         }];

      } else if(d.length == 4) {
         obj['label'] = d[0];
         obj['value'] = [{
            'label': d[1],
            'value': [{
               label: d[2],
               value: [
                  {
                     label: d[3],
                     value: [value]
                  }
               ]
            }]
         }];
      }
      arr.push(obj);
   })
   console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
}

init();
```

Can anyone guide me how can i achve this?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const inputItems = [{
        "raw_name": "At high school",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "At high school",
        "type": "education_statuses",
        "path": [
            "Demographics",
            "Education",
            "Education level"
        ]
    },
    {
        "raw_name": "At university",
        "id": "2",
        "name": "At university",
        "type": "education_statuses",
        "path": [
            "Demographics",
            "Education",
            "Education level"
        ]
    },
    {
        "raw_name": "At university (postgraduate)",
        "id": "7",
        "name": "At university (postgraduate)",
        "type": "education_statuses",
        "path": [
            "Interest",
            "Sports"
        ]
    },
    {
        "raw_name": "Doctorate degree",
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Doctorate degree",
        "type": "education_statuses",
        "path": [
            "Interest",
            "Sports"
        ]
    },
    {
        "raw_name": "Foundation degree",
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Foundation degree",
        "type": "education_statuses",
        "path": [
            "Demographics",
            "Education"
        ]
    }
];

const outputItemValues = [];

function getOrCreateOutputItemValue(path) {
    let curOutputItemValues = outputItemValues;
    for (let pathPart of path) {
        let outputItem = curOutputItemValues.find(({ label }) => label === pathPart);
        if (!outputItem) {
            outputItem = {
                "label": pathPart,
                "value": []
            };
            curOutputItemValues.push(outputItem);
        }
        curOutputItemValues = outputItem.value;
    }

    return curOutputItemValues;
}

for (let item of inputItems) {
    getOrCreateOutputItemValue(item.path).push(item);
}

console.log((outputItemValues));
```